# Linear combinations of reducible polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

My question concerns the sums of two reducible polynomials with bounded coefficients. In particular, for every $d \geq 2$ does there exist a number $C(d) > 0$ such that for any two co-prime reducible polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $d$ there exist integers $u,v$ such that $|u|, |v| \leq C(d)$ and $uf(x) + vg(x)$ is irreducible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "non-proportional", but if $f(x)=x(x-1)$ and $g(x)=x(x-2)$....

Comment: Presumably you mean coprime, not non-proportional.  Regardless, surely $C$ must be allowed to grow with the degree.  For example, choose $f$, $g$, and $uf+vg$ for small $u$ and $v$ to vanish at distinct integers.

Comment: Ah yes, $C$ should be a function of the degree, I will fix that. And yes, co-prime is the appropriate condition

Comment: I'm not sure C exists for d=0.  Do you know of a bound that permits ua+vb  to be prime when a and b are composite and coprime integers? Gerhard "Thinking Of Really Simple Cases" Paseman, 2016.11.17.

Comment: @Gerhard Paseman I put in the condition $d \geq 2$

Comment: This does not cure. If you know two composite coprime constants $a$ and $b$ such that $ua+vb$ are composite (say, divisible by $p_{uv}q_{uv}$) for all small $u$ and $v$, then you may take $f=ax^d$ and $g=b(x-N)^d$, where $N$ is the product of all $p_{uv}q_{uv}$.Then $uf+vg$ will still be divisible by $p_{uv}q_{uv}$.

Comment: And surely such constants exist: they can be constructed via the Chinese remainders theorem.

Comment: Can we fix this by modifying the question to be about polynomials over the rationals?